# Checkstyle error with LineLength and JavadocMethod

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

Yesterday I've updated Gradle wrapper (to version 6.1) in a personal project ([lifx-client](https://github.com/gilbertotcc/lifx-client)).
In this project I use [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/) to verify some rules on the code.
After the update task `:checkstyleMain` fails with the following error:

```sh
$ ./gradlew checkstyleMain
> Task :checkstyleMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/me/Projects/Miscellanea/
  lifx-client/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath { ...
```

After making some tests with the Checkstyle configuration file (you can see it at [checkstyle.xml](https://github.com/gilbertotcc/lifx-client/blob/develop/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml)), I've found that the error disappears if I comment out the modules:

```xml
    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="max" value="120"/>
      <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
    </module>
```

and

```xml
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
      <property name="allowMissingJavadoc" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="true"/>
      <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
      <property name="minLineCount" value="2"/>
      <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override,Test,Before,Given,When,Then,And"/>
      <property name="allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" value="true"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF"/>
    </module>
```

Any hints about the issue and/or how to fix it?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find exact error message of checkstyle library from your checkstyle plugin.

You most likely are facing known breaking compatibility changes in checksyle library.
Please review https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html
search for "JavadocMethod" and "LineLength", open related Guthub issues and you will see "Migration note" that explains how to upgrade config to resolve issue.

Comment: I had to remove also `minLineCount`. But I solved. Thx